# How can I pass command line parameters to tf.app.flags via PyCharm?

Tags: tensorflow, pycharm

When I pass command line parameters to my Python program via PyCharm, I find them as usual in `sys.argv`, but `tf.app.flags.FLAGS` instead reports empty strings.

If I run the same program outside PyCharm (from command line), then tf.app.flags.FLAGS reports the expected command line parameter values.

See screenshot below to see how I pass command line parameters in PyCharm.

Here a short program that reproduces the issue:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sys import argv

flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS

# command line flags
flags.DEFINE_string('input', '', "input file (.p)")

def main(_):
    print('Parameters', argv)
    print('input', FLAGS.input or 'is empty')

# parses flags and calls the `main` function above
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

If I run it from command line, I get the expected output:

```
python3 issue.py --input my_data.p
Parameters ['issue.py', '--input', 'my_data.p']
input my_data.p
```

But from PyCharm, `input` is set to an empty string:

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/fanta/workspace/CarND-Transfer-Learning-Lab/issue.py "--input my_data.p"
Parameters ['/home/fanta/workspace/CarND-Transfer-Learning-Lab/issue.py', '--input my_data.p']
input is empty
```

How can I get `input` to contain the command line parameter, using Tensorflow's `tf.app.flags.FLAGS` and PyCharm?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't put the script parameters into quotation marks `"..."`. Just write

```
--input_data my_data.p
```

in the `Script Parameter` fields in your screenshot.